# How to create a noise texture like this website's

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, texture

How would I go about making a texture similar to the one used throughout [this site](http://pulpfingers.com/):

[image]

Is it some kind of noise pattern?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's a noise effect that you can recreate using Photoshop or CSS. You can see it better in the [background image](http://pulpfingers.com/wp-content/themes/pulpfingers/images/background.png) of the website.

### Noise Effect in Photoshop

---

You can recreate it by adding a noise filter to a colored layer.

Go to `Filter > Noise > Add Noise...`, and select the Amount.

[image] ([Source](http://www.tutorialsbucket.com/noise-texture-background-effect-in-adobe-photoshop-cs5))

Then use transparency to make it more subtle. You can also invert the layer colors if you want a light noise effect instead.

### Noise Effect in CSS

---

There is also a CSS script that created noise. I haven't tried it but it looks really good, I didn't know it existed. It's called [CSS Noise](http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/demos/css-noise/), and all you need to do is call it using a class:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Transparency on the blur layer is what i was missing. Amazing what a little noise can do.

Comment: Indeed. And I just found a nice way of doing it in CSS, editing now.

Comment: Hum. I think that noise is cheating. I think it is a png file embeded as a code. :o)

Answer (score 2):

### Noise Filters in GIMP

Below are examples of factory noise filters in a default GIMP 2.6 installation.

[image] Source image (unfiltered)

[image]
Various highly configurable noise filters with default settings
(**1.** Film grain **2.** HSV noise **3.** Pick **4.** RGB noise **5.** Slur **6.** Spread)

By choosing different settings or combining these effects we can achieve anything from subtle to impressive effects:

[image] HSV noise (2) with stronger effect setting.

Additional noise filters can be added from the [GIMP Plugin Registry](http://registry.gimp.org/). The Film grain script (1) is not installed in GIMP 2.8. but can also be added from the plugin registry.